# JSON output for items

Tags: php, json

I am having a code like below . I am reading a JSON URL and echo some items with some if conditions. I am in need to re echo the selected items in JSON format.

```
<?php
// Array of trains to list
//Arrival train list
$trainNumbers = array(
    9021,11077
);

$json      = file_get_contents('myURL.json');
$trainData = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($trainData[0] as $train) {

    $trainNumber = $train[0][0];
    if (in_array($trainNumber, $trainNumbers)) {
        $fields = array(
            'train_no',
            'train_name',
            'dep_date',
            'dep_station',
            'dep_log',
            'dep_lat',
            'arr_station',
            'delay_time',
            'new_lat',
            'new_long',
            'new_station',
            'new_station_name',
            'time_delay',
            'station_left'
        );
        foreach ($train[0] as $i => $dataField) {
            echo $fields[$i] . " - {$dataField}\n";
            $trains[$trainNumber][$fields[$i]] = $datafield;
        }
        echo "\n";

    }
}
?>
```

The above code display data like

```
train_no - 09021
train_name - MUMBAI BANDRA T - JAMMU TAWI Exp (SPL)
dep_date - 2013-05-06
dep_station - BRSQ
dep_log - 28.613196
dep_lat - 77.14046
arr_station - BRAR SQUARE
delay_time - 150
new_lat - 28.659977
new_long - 77.156425
new_station - UMB
new_station_name - AMBALA CANT JN
time_delay - 48
station_left - 67

train_no - 11077
train_name - PUNE - JAMMU TAWI Jhelum Express
dep_date - 2013-05-06
dep_station - HET
dep_log - 26.611628
dep_lat - 77.943449
arr_station - HETAMPUR
delay_time - 56
new_lat - 26.697312
new_long - 77.905769
new_station - DHO
new_station_name - DHAULPUR
time_delay - 44
station_left - 93
```

How can I echo the output again in JSON format ?

on edit as suggested below

```
$data[$fields[$i]]= " - {$dataField}\n";
      echo json_encode($data);
```

I am getting this error

[image]

Here is teh JSON output

http://pastebin.com/7EeVg8X9

Actually in this script we have list for 100's trains so I called some of the trains from that.

Comment: You are not just simply echoing the output as JSON - the error you are getting seems to indicate that you are trying to parse it as well. Note that you have multiple JSON objects being output, which is the cause of the error.

Comment: @Perception Then how and wheer should I change to get the JSON values

Comment: Confirm or deny, you are trying to select just those nodes (trains) in the JSON that match the selected train numbers, and return the entire result as a valid JSON array?

Comment: yes I confirm that I am selecting the train and calling the fields of it. You see the result when I run the script but when I am trying to show that output as JSON it throws an error.

Comment: @Perception I have posted the original JSON link. Now you can also check

Comment: Ok, I see that you are transforming the data being retrieved from the external website. Your code is almost correct, you just need to surround the whole thing with square brackets (`[]`), and separate each value with a comma.

Comment: @Perception Can you please show an example. I didnt get where to change .

Comment: Sure, there is associated code, so I've shown in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your problem is that you are outputting each mapped 'train' as a separate item. In order for the output to represent valid JSON, at a minimum the separate elements should be collected into an array. Here is a slightly modified version of your program:

```
<?php
// Fields to be translated
$fields = array(
    'train_no',
    'train_name',
    'dep_date',
    'dep_station',
    'dep_log',
    'dep_lat',
    'arr_station',
    'delay_time',
    'new_lat',
    'new_long',
    'new_station',
    'new_station_name',
    'time_delay',
    'station_left'
);

// Array of trains to list
//Arrival train list
$trainNumbers = array(
    9021,11077
);

$json      = file_get_contents('myurl.json');
$trainData = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($trainData[0] as $train) {

    $trainNumber = $train[0][0];
    if (in_array($trainNumber, $trainNumbers)) {

        foreach ($train[0] as $i => $dataField) {
            $data[$fields[$i]]= $dataField;
        }

        $translated[] = $data;
    }
}

echo json_encode($translated);
?>
```

Which outputs (after formatting with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)):

```
[
    {
        "train_no": "09021",
        "train_name": "MUMBAI BANDRA T - JAMMU TAWI Exp (SPL)",
        "dep_date": "2013-05-06",
        "dep_station": "HUK",
        "dep_log": "28.801247",
        "dep_lat": "77.102394",
        "arr_station": "HOLAMBI KALAN",
        "delay_time": "172",
        "new_lat": "28.846516",
        "new_long": "77.085357",
        "new_station": "UMB",
        "new_station_name": "AMBALA CANT JN",
        "time_delay": 70,
        "station_left": 64
    },
    {
        "train_no": "11077",
        "train_name": "PUNE - JAMMU TAWI Jhelum Express",
        "dep_date": "2013-05-06",
        "dep_station": "BHA",
        "dep_log": "27.06879445",
        "dep_lat": "77.96653748",
        "arr_station": "BHANDAI",
        "delay_time": "59",
        "new_lat": "27.157722",
        "new_long": "77.989883",
        "new_station": "AGC",
        "new_station_name": "AGRA CANTT",
        "time_delay": 45,
        "station_left": 92
    }
]
```

You could choose to use a different kind of JSON output (for example a root object with each train keyed by name, or whatever else). Just extend the same principle as shown above in order to generate valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode for encodeing data into json

```
      $data[$fields[$i]]= $dataField;
      echo json_encode($data);
```

You will get more help from [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: it worked but the output is not perfect JSON format . It shows parser error

Comment: @Deonia,could you please check with $data[$fields[$i]]= " - {$dataField}\n"; to $data[$fields[$i]]= " - {$dataField}";

Comment: I did check same response :(

Comment: I have posted the original JSON file . Now you can also check